# Is React event name equals to its vanilla JS name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A little bit strange question i know.. :) I try to dispatch a click event on element without success. here is the clickable element:

```
<div
        className="just-humash-text"
        id="one-column-container"
        onClick={() => {
          if (!isBookmarkLineSelectionMode) setIsNikudMode(!isNikudMode);
          setIsFirstScroll(false);
        }}
```

> 

and here is the event dispatch (in another component):

```
useEffect(() => {
  ref.current.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
    const humashTextElem = document.querySelector('.just-humash-text');
    console.log(humashTextElem);
    humashTextElem.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
  });
}, []);
```

(the `console.log` is working and logging the correct element..)

thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are trying to use a dispatchEvent instead of using context or redux or a lifted state? Basically, Reacts events are Synthetic Events

Comment: its an option but in my situation its more comfortable to use dispatchEvent..

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events Direct DOM manipulation is an anti-pattern in react.